# How to assign key to each Item or value in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have an array like this:

```
[link1,link2,link3]
```

But I want it like this:

```
[uri:link1,uri:link2,uri:link3]
```

Please guide me over this. Thanks.

Comment: That's not a valid array in JavaScript. Why do you want it like that?

Comment: Since `[uri:link1,uri:link2,uri:link3]` is not valid JavaScript we don't really know what result you really want. So you want `[{uri: link1}, {uri: link2}, ...]` or `{uri1: link1, uri2: link2, ...}`? Having an array of objects with a single property is a bit unusual but of course might be necessary. Please provide more context about what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you could try by mapping your array and returning new array of object like this

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const newArr = array1.map(i => {return {uri: i}})

console.log(newArr);
// > Array [Object { uri: 1 }, Object { uri: 2 }, Object { uri: 3 }, Object { uri: 4 }]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need in the form of (Array of objects)

```
var test = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

function setID(item, index) {
  var fullname = {"id: ": item};
  return fullname;
}

var output = test.map(setID);
console.log(output);
```

output: [
{
"id: ": "a"
},
{
"id: ": "b"
},
{
"id: ": "c"
},
{
"id: ": "d"
}
]

Comment: OP didn't ask for an array of objects. There is not an object in sight. It is unclear what OP is actually asking.

Comment: ok , may be help others

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.from! It's really simple and faster.

```
var test = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var newTest = Array.from(test, val => 'id: '+ val);
console.log(newTest);
```

output: [
"id: a",
"id: b",
"id: c",
"id: d"
]